# simple-salesforce bulk upsert not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am trying to bulk upsert records into Salesforce using the `simple-salesforce` Python library.

I have a list of dictionaries called `categories` with the format `[{'FooNumber': '001', 'Category': 'A'}, {'FooNumber': '002', 'Category': 'B'}, {'FooNumber': '003', 'Category': 'C'}...]`

When I try `upsert` with one record at a time it works:

`sf.Foo.upsert('FooNumber/001', {'Category': 'A'})`

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#using-bulk), the following bulk upsert code should work:

`sf.bulk.Foo.upsert(scores, 'FooNumber', batch_size=1000)`

But, I get the following error:

`TypeError: upsert() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_size'`

What is wrong with bulk upsert?

Note: I cannot make the code reproducible since I am working with private data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you need to update your `simple_salesforce`. This capability was added in `simple_salesforce` 1.1.0, the latest release.